# scanning in and grabbing a specific token

Tags: java, algorithm, palindrome

I am having trouble with what I have been testing for a few days now.

All using Stacks and Queues

```
Sample.txt : My mom and dad both think I will do good at my gig tomorrow.
```

I have a GUI that attach's a file and parses the file for Palindromes. I want to for instance,

I can find `mom` as a palindrome, and since `mom.length()` is == to `3` i would then grab the third token from `mom`, which in this case would be `both`. I am able to grab all of these palindromes correctly, just at a loss on how i would traverse tokens that i haven't 'read' in yet?

my method is,

```
public void fileDecode() throws FileNotFoundException
    {


            while(scanInput.hasNext())
            {
                int counter = 0;
                int nextPalindrome = 0;
                String token = scanInput.next();
                Stack<Character> stk = new Stack<Character>();
                Queue<Character> que = new LinkedList<Character>();
                for (int i = 0; i < token.length(); ++i)
                {
                    stk.push(token.charAt(i));
                    que.add(token.charAt(i));

                }
                for (int j = 0; j < token.length(); ++j)
                {
                        char tempStk = stk.pop();
                        char tempQue = que.remove();

                        if (tempStk == tempQue)
                        {
                            counter++;
                        }
                }

                if (counter == token.length())
                {
                   //build.append(token + " ");  #if i want to see the palindromes
                    nextPalindrome = token.length(); //the length/distance of the token desired
                } 

            }  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please remove the FileChooser and other extra paraphernalia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> just at a loss on how i would traverse tokens that i haven't 'read' in yet?

You read them and skip them. Just use a local variable which is usually 0, but once you find a palindrome you set it to the palindrome's length. Then before the checking logic you check this variable and continue the loop if it is greater than 0.

```
// Idea: there are 3 cases:
// 1. tokensToSkip is 0: process as normal (check for palindromeness)
// 2. tokensToSkip is 1: decrement it to 0, but process as normal
// 3. tokensToSkip is 2, 3, 4...: decrement it and skip (continue the while)
// Note that tokensToSkip will never be negative.

// Will skip tokensToSkip - 1 tokens
int tokensToSkip = 0;
while(scanInput.hasNext()) {
    String token = scanInput.next();
    // instead of the next two lines we could just have:
    //     if (--tokensToSkip > 0) continue;
    // only once, notice the -- operator in front.
    //
    // This would almost always work, but if tokensToSkip = Integer.MIN_VALUE
    // decrementing it will cause negative overflow and thus tokensToSkip will
    // become Integer.MAX_VALUE! To prevent this we have a check.
    if (tokensToSkip > 0) tokensToSkip--;

    // here tokensToSkip is already decremented, so this check is different
    // from the one above. For example is tokensToSkip == 1 before the line
    // above, now it is tokensToSkip == 0 and this second check fails.
    if (tokensToSkip > 0) continue;
    if (isPalindrome(token)) {
        tokensToSkip = token.length();
    }
    // ... other stuff ...
}
```

By the way, a more efficient way to implement `isPalindrome()` is:

```
static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() / 2; i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(s.length() - i - 1)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to understand this and think I do. I have a variable `int nextPalindrome` that holds the length of the palindrome it just found. This is the local variable I think you're speaking of. I'm just trying to consider how to implement that logic in my method here.

Comment: The name does not matter much, this is the line that does the skipping: `if (tokensToSkip > 0) continue;`

Comment: I meant, `nextPalindrome` is the local I'm referring to. In my implementation I renamed to `tokensToSkip` for readability. Note there is a -1 because if your palindrome has length 3, e.g. mom, you wanna skip only 2 tokens and  process the third, "both".

Comment: ohhhh didn't see comment above. the -1 is for the reason above. `if (tokensToSkip > 0){ tokensToSkip--;}` what is this doing? putting it into -1, etc? ensuring that tokensToSkip will never be > 0 unless a token was found?

Comment: No, if tokensToSkip > 0, you are in "skipping mode" and you will eat the next tokensToSkip - 1 tokens. You need the check because otherwise a some point tokensToSkip will become so small (negative) that it will wrap around and become positive again! This will happens only for extremely large inputs though

Comment: To sum up: tokensToSkip is 0: process as normal. tokensToSkip is 1: decrement and process as normal. tokensToSkip is > 1: decrement and skip.

Comment: I believe i understand what you are saying here in the comments, but i'm having a hard time referring that back to your initial block of code. Trying to draw all this up on my whiteboard. Could you maybe add some comments? sorry!

Comment: Anyways, the important thing here is the "skipping part" with the variable. The exact logic with all the off-by-one cases is just a detail.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to achieve the same functionality

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         while ( sc.hasNext()){
             String str = sc.nextLine();
             String words[] = str.split(" ");
             for ( int i=0; i < words.length; i++){
                 String reverseWord = new StringBuffer(words[i]).reverse().toString();
                 System.out.println("word:reverseWord:Palindrome:"+words[i]+":"+reverseWord+":"+words[i].equals(reverseWord));
             }
         }

  }

}
```

**EDIT:**

1) Read the line and split into words array

2) For each word, Use StringBuffer() and reverse() method and get reversed String

3) Compare if both these strings are equal. If equal, it is palindrome.

Comment: I am using Stacks and Queue's to achieve what is and isnt a palindrome, the only issue at hand is reading in a token, checking if its a palindrome, getting its length,  the only thing i havent been able to accomplish is grabbing the next token once i find out which one it needs to be

Comment: I suggest to replace Stack and Queues to check whether given string is Palindrome or not. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I see the simplicity of your alternative but there is much more to the question than what i'm asking that requires Stacks and Queue's. thanks

Comment: I changed the code. Read the complete line and check if each word is palindrome. You won't miss any thing from the input. Just replace System.in with your FileInputStream and everything works fine.

Comment: I am not trying to find out what is and is not a palindrome, i have achieved this already. In my question i was trying to figure out how to take the palindrome's length and go to the token accordingly

Comment: Once you read token with scanInput.next () irrespective of palindrome or not, you have already advanced in the stream. You are reading token as word and you will know it is palindrome or not after processing the word. IF I am not wrong, please let me know what are you skipping?